# Pot or cooler based mash tun?

Tags: mash-tun

What's the pros and cons about mash in coolers or pots? How to choose?

Comment: Chino tells the pros and cons listed as I asked, so I'm accepting his very good answer. But Denny's experience sharing was also very important to me to buy a cooler and give it a try. Thanks you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cooler as Mash Tun**

*Pros:* Relatively cheap and easy to modify with a bulkhead fitting and ball valve. Holds a steady temperature very well. Lighter weight, and therefore easier to clean.

*Cons:* Cannot be direct-fired, so any step mashing has to be done with additional infusions or by decoction - step infusions will increase your mash's water-to-grist ratio. Will not perform double duty as a kettle (but can be used for cold beverages).

**Kettle as Mash Tun**

*Pros:* Can be direct-fired for stepped mash schedules. Can be used in advanced homebrewing setups such as RIMS or HERMS systems. Can double as a kettle.

*Cons:* Higher cost. The kettle is not insulated, so it is harder to maintain a steady temperature. More difficult to modify to add a ball valve. Heavier, and therefore harder to clean, relatively speaking.

> How to choose?

It comes down to your budget and personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

I have used a cooler for 466 batches over the last 17 years.  I have tried using a pot to mash in and found I preferred the cooler because it held the temp so well.  I seldom find a need to do step mashes and in fact question their value.  But when I want to do one, it's a simple matter to simply infuse boiling water until I get to the temp step I'm going for.  You can see my equipment and methods at www.dennybrew.com